# Flexible height of plot in shiny app

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I´m searching for a method to change the `height` parameter in `plotOutput()` depending on an `input$..` value.

Any suggestions?

Samuel

Comment: what have you tried so far? please add code for a working shiny app up to the point where you are stuck.

Comment: the simplest solution would be to use `ggvis`: it lets you resize the plot without the need to program anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    numericInput("height", "height", 300),
    plotOutput("plot", height = "auto")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1:10)
    },
    height = function(x) input$height)
  }
)
```